# I need to upgrade my Active-Directory version but I need to upgrade my active directory

Tags: active-directory, msmq

I need to upgrade my Active-Directory version but I need to upgrade my active directory.
What are the newest Active-Directory versions I can have? And my client still must be Windows NT 4.0. What Active-Directory versions still support NT 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test yours environment as the support lifecycle for Microsoft Windows NT 4.0 Workstation ended June 30. Microsoft is retiring support for these products because the technology is outdated and can expose customers to security risks.

Would suggest you to please run these PowerShell command to get to know the Active Directory version for Windows NT 4.0.

```
Get-ADObject (Get-ADRootDSE).schemaNamingContext -Property objectVersion
```

Reference: https://eightwone.com/references/ad-schema-versions/

https://marclsitinfrablog.wordpress.com/windows-sharepoint-articles-posts/windows-server-articles-posts/windows-server-active-directory-schema-versions/

On these two above link it has shown what are the latest active directory supported for their respective window version.

Note: The AAD version for Windows NT 5.0 (Windows 2000) (1997-1999) was 13